# If eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, then matrix is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

If eigenvalues of a matrix are $1$, or $-1$, or both of them, does that necessarily means that the matrix is orthogonal?

The only thing I'm certain about is that the matrix is non-singular, due to absence of zero among the eigenvalues.

Comment: if $A$ is your matrix, what is $A^tA$?

Comment: No, counter examples are matrices in non-trivial [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) with eigenvalue $1$ (e.g $\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}$ ).

Comment: @achillehui, thank you, is there an counterexample with both 1 and -1?

Comment: $(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{smallmatrix})$ has both $1$ and $-1$ as eigenvalues.

Comment: @push, take a diagonal matrix with $\pm 1$ along the diagonal and choose one of the off-diagonal elements to be non-zero. This matrix has eigenvalues of $\pm 1$ and is not orthogonal.

Comment: @achillehui, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$ have to be orthogonal to the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$ in order for the matrix to be orthogonal. A $2\times2$ counterexample using this idea is not difficult to construct. For example, let $M$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ for which
$$
                    M\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right] \\
                    M\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]=-\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1\end{array}\right].
$$
Then $M$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, but the eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues are not orthgonal. To find $M$,
\begin{align}
        M\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right]
          & = M\left(x\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right]+(y-x)\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]\right) \\
          & = x\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right]+(x-y)\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1\end{array}\right] \\
          & = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\2 & -1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right]
\end{align}
So a simple counterexample is
$$
     M = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 2 & -1\end{array}\right].
$$
It is easy to check that $M$ has the correct eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\pm 1$. And $M$ is not orthogonal:
$$
             M^{\perp}M = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 2 & -1\end{array}\right]
           = \left[\begin{array}{cc}5 & -2 \\ -2 & 1\end{array}\right]\ne I.
$$